# Topological Sort using Boost::topological_sort

Tags: boost, generic-programming, topological-sort

I am trying to use topological_sort function of boost.

I am using the boost::adjacency_list with setS and listS as the underlying storage for edges and vertices.

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::listS, boost::bidirectionalS > SizerGraph;  
    SizerGraph sizerGraph;  
    typedef boost::graph_traits<SizerGraph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;  
    boost::topological_sort(sizerGraph, std::ostream_iterator<Vertex>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Compilation results in errors. (g++ 3.4.6)

> /usr/include/boost/property_map.hpp:349: error: no match for
>   'operator+' in '((const
>   boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
>   boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map,
>   boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const
>   boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>,
>   boost::default_color_type,
>   boost::default_color_type&>*)this)->boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
>   boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map,
>   boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const
>   boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>,
>   boost::default_color_type, boost::default_color_type&>::iter +
>   boost::get [with PropertyMap =
>   boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map,
>   boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const
>   boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>,
>   Reference = const boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, K =
>   void*](((const boost::put_get_helper,
>   boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const
>   boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>
>
> > &)((const boost::put_get_helper,
> >     boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const
> >     boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>
> >     *)(((const boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map,
> >     boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const
> >     boost::detail::error_property_not_found&,
> >     boost::vertex_index_t>*)((const
> >     boost::iterator_property_map<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >,
> >     boost::adj_list_vertex_property_map,
> >     boost::detail::error_property_not_found, const
> >     boost::detail::error_property_not_found&, boost::vertex_index_t>,
> >     boost::default_color_type, boost::default_color_type&>*)this)) +
> >     8u))), ((void* const&)((void* const*)(&v))))'
>
> /usr/include/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2264: error: no
>   matching function for call to `get_property_value(boost::no_property&,
>   boost::vertex_index_t)

However, **using vecS as the underlying storage mechanism for vertices** results in clean compilation.

Is my usage of listS for vertices breaking any concept requirement?

Comment: Hi, googling on the boost discussion group I found [this](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2003/01/43252.php). Need to try it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but the error message starts out:

> No match for 'operator+' in blah .. iterator ..

When you use VecS, you get a vector - whose iterators are random access, and support operator+

When you use ListS, you get a list - whose iterators are bidirectional, and do not support operator+

Comment: You are correct. However, the documentation says that the graph should be a model of the VertexListGraph concept [boost topo-sort](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/doc/topological_sort.html). Seems that this concept does not require random access requirement on the vertices. Correct me if I am wrong!